# How to shorten nested for loops and if conditions coming after each other in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, nest, large-data, processing-efficiency

I have a Python script, that collects matching 5x5 crosswords from a 10000 words dataset (5 letter words). It is working, but it would take a year to be finished. Is there a way to make this code more efficient?
I’m only an amateur programmer and a little bit lost, so maybe there are better approaches, too.

This is the code I wrote:

It goes through the words and at the end of the line, if everything matches, writes ten words to a text file.

```py
allWords = open('allWords.txt').read().splitlines()
f = open('finalSolutions.txt', 'a')

for v1 in allWords:
    for h1 in allWords:
        if h1[0] == v1[0] and h1 != v1:
            for v2 in allWords:
                if v2[0] == h1[1] and v2 != h1:
                    for h2 in allWords:
                        if h2[0] == v1[1] and h2[1] == v2[1] and h2 != v1 and h2 != v2:
                            for v3 in allWords:
                                if v3[0] == h1[2] and v3[1] == h2[2] and v3 != h1 and v3 != h2:
                                    for h3 in allWords:
                                        if h3[0] == v1[2] and h3[1] == v2[2] and h3[2] == v3[2] and h3 != v1 and h3 != v2 and h3 != v3:
                                            for v4 in allWords:
                                                if v4[0] == h1[3] and v4[1] == h2[3] and v4[2] == h3[3] and v4 != h1 and v4 != h2 and v4 != h3:
                                                    for h4 in allWords:
                                                        if h4[0] == v1[3] and h4[1] == v2[3] and h4[2] == v3[3] and h4[3] == v4[3] and h4 != v1 and h4 != v2 and h4 != v3 and h4 != v4:
                                                            for v5 in allWords:
                                                                if v5[0] == h1[4] and v5[1] == h2[4] and v5[2] == h3[4] and v5[3] == h4[4] and v5 != h1 and v5 != h2 and v5 != h3 and v5 != h4:
                                                                    for h5 in allWords:
                                                                        if h5[0] == v1[4] and h5[1] == v2[4] and h5[2] == v3[4] and h5[3] == v4[4] and h5[4] == v5[4] and h5 != v1 and h5 != v2 and h5 != v3 and h5 != v4 and h5 != v5:
                                                                            lines = [h1, ', ', h2, ', ', h3, ', ', h4, ', ', h5, ', ', v1, ', ', v2, ', ', v3, ', ', v4, ', ', v5, '\n']
                                                                            f.writelines(lines)

f.close()
```

The input is a textfile, for example like this (but with 10000 meaningful words):

```
abcde
acegi
bcdef
cdefg
defgh
efghi
opdka
bdfhj
cegik
dfhjl
egikm
ghijk
ijklm
```

...and the output is another textfile, in this case it is:

```
acegi, bdfhj, cegik, dfhjl, egikm, abcde, cdefg, efghi, ghijk, ijklm
abcde, cdefg, efghi, ghijk, ijklm, acegi, bdfhj, cegik, dfhjl, egikm
```

Comment: you need another approach for your task. Making 10fold loop on a 10k elements makes 10_000 power 10 iterations. It is not doable!

Comment: @Psytho Did you not see all the ifs?

Comment: How did you estimate that it would take a year?

Comment: can you provide a sample example, where what is input, what you are trying to do, what you want to get ?

Comment: So the same word is allowed to appear multiple times horizontally or multiple times vertically?

Comment: @KellyBundy I did of course.

Comment: OK, I added a sample input and the desired output (that actually working, but slowly and inefficiently). I will try the suggestions, thank you. But you can write more possible solutions.